# How can I make a spawner that summons Items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been playing around with command blocks, and I'm trying to create a spawner that will summon an item of my choosing every random amount of time (between 4-7 seconds)

I tried using command generators, but none allow using ITEMS as the mob.

I then tried using command generators to spawn a slime with 1 heart and 5-second fire and drops an item of my choosing every x seconds.

Then the mobs didn't spawn at all, yes I had it on hard and It was dark.

So I'm a bit confused as to why my spawner is failing to spawn mobs, or why I can't seem to find item spawners anywhere on the internet.

I've seen people make spawners in servers that spawn emeralds or diamonds (they even have the little emerald swirling around inside the spawner)

Could anyone help me out here? I am using 1.14.

Comment: @DanBron that is incorrect, spawners can spawn in any entity from falling sand to exp orbs

Comment: People downvote on stack exchange all the time, its the price of posting here... No one owes you an explanation, but if I were to guess its probably because its fairly easy to figure out that custom spawners can be created using mcedit and sethblings filter.

Comment: …or using this: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format#Block_entity_format

Comment: @joeybab3 The whole point of asking here was for an EASIER WAY... *facepalm*
Im trying to make HUNDREDS of spawners with different items. You think I want to manually filter every single one in mcedit... seriously

Comment: As opposed to... manually typing out a long command? Yes, I would think that as it would take less time... You won't get anywhere in life being rude to the people who try to help you...

Comment: @joeybab3 lol im double facepalming now. You paste the command in the block, it setblocks the spawner, you change the item, ctrl middle click it, and within minutes you can have many many done.
Check Bearb001's answer

Comment: People can't help you properly if you don't give them all the information.  You've added extra info here in the comments that should probably be part of your question.  I'd recommend editing it to include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this command to `/setblock` a spawner at the position where you are currently standing that will summon diamonds:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:spawner{SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:item",Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b},Weight:1}}
```