# Custom Minecraft 1.8 spawners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a minecraft 1.8 server and am trying to make a mob spawner that spawns items.  This example:[How can I make a spawner that summons Items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/356179/how-can-i-make-a-spawner-that-summons-items) works on new versions of minecraft but not on 1.8.  It seems that any mob spawners placed down by command blocks don't work.  The following command:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:zombie},Delay:299}
```

Creates an empty mob spawner that does not spawn anything.  I am using minecraft forge with worldedit but no other mods.  How can I fix this?

Comment: 1.8 was years ago.

Comment: But it does seem like you put effort into this so I upvoted it :)

Comment: @BronsonHunter lots of people still use 1.8, its probably the second most used version.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is generated from [mcstacker](https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/mcstacker1.10.php) 1.8, 1.9, and 1.10 version.  The following code should place a zombie spawner.

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:Zombie,Delay:299}
```

The next command should place a spawner that spawns diamonds.

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:Item,SpawnData:{Item:{id:diamond,Count:1}},Delay:299}
```

Try that.  The command isn't tested, but mcstacker usually works for me.  It may not for you because you are on a server.  You can change it with mcstacker.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that you can get custom mob spawners in Java Edition and that the only spawners you can get are Pig Spawners. They way you can obtain pig spawners is using the `/give` command. Example: `/give @p 52 1`

Comment: I don't think that is true since I have seen a video where there is a spawner spawning fireworks and other things.  But it seems like I might have to use skript.

Comment: If your trying to get custom spawners on Vanilla Minecraft, that is not possible. I believe that you would have to use plugins/mods. Do you know if in the video that they used commands?

Comment: @darthvader1925 it is possible.  I only know how to do it in 1.13 and up.  Maybe be the same process.